# How to write query in description in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Tables:

```
posts - id, title, description, vote_count
post_votes - id, user_id, post_id, vote
```

My sql query:

```
SELECT posts.*, (select vote from post_votes where post_votes.post_id = posts.id and post_votes.user_id = 1) as my_vote FROM posts;
```

I am new to RoR and ActiveRecord. Can anyone help me writing the above query in ActiveRecord?

I am using Rails 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve above query in ActiveRecord:

```
Post.select("posts.*, (select vote from post_votes where post_votes.post_id = posts.id and post_votes.user_id = 1) as my_vote").order('created_at DESC')
```